# tooltip with scrollbar using tooltipster

Tags: node.js, scroll, tooltipster

I have to use bind html inside tooltip using `tooltipster jquery`. But I have to bind more data inside tooltip.

How to implement scrollbar inside tooltip using tooltipster jquery? I have to tooltipster jquery and tooltipster css.

I have used code below:

```
$('#MainContent').tooltipster({
   trigger:"click",
   contentAsHTML: true,
   content: thtmlcnt,
   position:"right",
   autoClose:"true",
   positionTracker:true
});
```

Please give some solution how to implement scroll bar inside tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by giving the content a max-height for example

> jQuery

```
   $('#MainContent').tooltipster({
       trigger:"click",
       contentCloning: false,
       content: $('.content').detach(),
       position:"right",
       autoClose:"true",
       positionTracker:true
   });
```

> HTML

```
<div class="content" style="max-height:100px">
    //Your content here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```css
.tooltipster-base {
  max-height: 300px;
  pointer-events: all !important;
}
.tooltipster-box {
  display: inline-block !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/louisameline/tooltipster-scrollableTip/blob/master/tooltipster-scrollableTip.js